# Elastic4s - HTTPS connection to Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm trying to connect to Elasticsearch using elastic4s-http vis https but can't find a way to use https instead of http.

I'm currently using:

```
HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(config.getString("services.elasticsearch.host"), config.getInt("services.elasticsearch.port")))
```

to connect to the instance.

I seem to be getting a connection as I see this in the logs:

> INFO com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.HttpClient$ - Creating HTTP client on http://host:port
>
> DEBUG com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.search.SearchImplicits$SearchHttpExecutable$ - Executing search request: {"query":{"match":{"status":{"query":"Listed"}}}}
>
> DEBUG com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.search.SearchImplicits$SearchHttpExecutable$ - Executing elastic request POST:/myindex/_search?
>
> DEBUG com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.search.SearchImplicits$SearchHttpExecutable$ - {"query":{"match":{"status":{"query":"Listed"}}}}```

but then I get this:

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

and no response is returned.

Any advice on how I can get https to work would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need version 5.4.4 or higher, and then you enable SSL on the connection string.

```
val uri = "elasticsearch://host:port,host:port,host:port?ssl=true"
val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(uri))
```

Or in your specific case:

```
val host = config.getString("services.elasticsearch.host")
val port = config.getString("services.elasticsearch.port")
val uri = s"elasticsearch://$host:$port?ssl=true"
val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(uri))
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass authentication user/password with this set-up?

Comment: You can do `elasticsearch://user:name@host:port,host:port,host:port?ssl=true` in the latest releases.